# data frame leads to deleting xlsx file sheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a problem when parsing a Microsoft Office Spreadsheet.
Whenever I write on a particular sheet, another sheet gets removed.

```
wb2 = load_workbook('alldata.xlsx')

shtname=wb2.get_sheet_names()
shtname.remove('D0')

dfs = pd.read_excel(
    'alldata.xlsx', sheetname=None,header=0,
    dtype={
        'Open Price (Rs.)': np.float64,
        'Close Price (Rs.)': np.float64,
        'High Price (Rs.)': np.float
    },
    thousands=','
)
dfg = pd.read_excel(
    'sorted.xlsx', sheetname='sheet1', header=0,
    dtype={
        'Open Price (Rs.)': np.float64,
        'Close Price (Rs.)': np.float64,
        'High Price (Rs.)': np.float
    },
    thousands=','
)



dft=dfs['D2']
dft.to_excel('alldata.xlsx',header=True,sheet_name='D3')
```

This leads to deletion of other sheets present in `alldata.xlsx`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made your English a bit clearer and reformatted so that it does not require horizontal scrolling. Also, you clearly have `shtname.remove('D0')` in your code. Maybe you should explain that the problem is that it also removes other sheets. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly telling it to do so! By `dft=dfs['D2']` you are intentionally slicing only one part of the original dfs.

You are creating new object `dft` that only contains D2 part of the `dfs` and then saving it over the existing excel sheet. It's no wonder the rest of the parts got lost.

Comment: Opps,sorry for that silly mistek actually i try to copy one sheet data and write it on another sheet within same excel file using pandas data frame could you help me